# How to use variables in a PHP evaluation in a rule?

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints

I created a rule with the actions "Provide a variable: mynumber" and "Grant points to a user". I'd like to evaluate the points with PHP, using "mynumber". For some reason, I can't use `$mynumber`, although that is possible in the PHP evalution of the sections 'Operation' and 'Description'. As the replacement pattern `[mynumber]` is available, I tried to use it in my code with and without the square brackets, but in both cases, I get the error:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant mynumber - assumed 'mynumber' in
>   eval() (line 1 of
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\rules\modules\php.eval.inc(146) :
>   eval()'d code).

Is this a missing feature, a bug in the Rules module or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem is caused by the way Rules handles integers and numbers in general. Instead of trying to calculate the Userpoints in the action "Grant points to a user", one should provide a new variable earlier.

1. Provide a new variable (**text type!**), called "Number", with the necessary PHP code (wrapped with `<?php ... ?>`). One can then use earlier calculated results like `$mynumber`.
2. Convert "Number" to an integer, called "Points".
3. Grant "Points" to the user.

Hopefully, Rules will cope a little bit better with numbers in the future, but until then, I hope this trick helps a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this,  use [variable module](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) and define variable which you want use in rule.

To define a variable you need to write custom module , which will contain following function

```
function My_module_variable_info() {
  $variables['rainbow_count'] = array(
  // 'name' isn't really necessary, as it will get populated from the key of this array above.
 'name' => 'rainbow_count',
 'title' => t('Number of Rainbows'),
 'type' => 'number',
 'group' => 'UserPoints Config',
 'token' => TRUE,
'default' => 0,
'description' => t('Specify the number of rainbows.')
); 

}
```

Set value for variable which you want use in rule through :

`configuration>>variables>>modules>>My_module_...`

Now go to rules >action> grant points to a user > Points:

Set `data type =current-user:uid`  and put `return variable_get('rainbow_count');` code in PHP evaluation.

This solution worked for me,hope will help you also.